# Range based for loop over an optional for generic programming

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a templated function which gets optionals or vectors.  I'd like to be able to have a for loop over all elements (when optional, I realize it will be one iteration, but expect the compiler will do the right thing and optimize away the loop).  This would prevent some duplicate code with template specializations to handle optionals.

```
template <typename Container>
void Operate( const Container& c){
  for(const auto& element : c){
    foo(element);
  }
}

int main(){
  std::optional<int> a = ...;
  std::vector<float> b = ...;
  ...
  Operate(a); // only executes `foo(element)` if `c` has_value().
  Operate(b); // executes `foo(element)` for each element in `c`.
}
```

How do I make this work with `std::optional` for `Container`?  Why isn't this part of the standard library in the spirit of generic programming?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are after here. `std::optional` is not a container. Do you have a container of `std::optional` and you want it to auto-skip when the option is false?

Comment: Please show the different ways you would call this function.

Comment: This isn't the first discussion of whether to allow iterating over `optional`, but it's by no means a feature that everyone expects, so it's no surprise it wasn't included in the original proposal. There was already enough hubbub about `optional<T&>` delaying its inclusion, let alone with another feature that turns out to be a bit controversial.

Comment: @user4581301 optional is a "container" with fixed number of elements, 0 or 1.

Comment: [A lot of work goes into making something a C++ container](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general). I fall into that group chris mentioned that don't expect container behaviour from `std::optional` along with the group that doesn't quite see the point. Might as well make everything iteratable.

Comment: Instead of using `std::optional` you could just use `std::vector` and only put *zero* or *one* elements in it.

Comment: @Galik, You could, but it's the wrong type at the API level (not only have you lost the suitable name and API, but what stops code from adding more by mistake?), has different performance characteristics (vectors use dynamic allocations while optionals don't), and has different compile-time support (pre-C++20, you can't use vectors at all, and even in C++20 you can't, e.g., `constexpr vector v = foo();`).

Comment: [they're cooking up a `views::maybe` and `views::nullable` proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p1255r10.pdf) that does exactly what you're looking for @Zac: treating `std::optional` as an iterable with cardinality 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

`std::optional` is not a container that satisfies the requirements of a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), as:

- it is not an array type
- it does not have `begin()` and `end()` methods
- it does not have specializations of `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.

So, you will just have to overload `Operate()` itself to take in an `std::optional` parameter, eg:

```cpp
template <typename Container>
void Operate( const Container& c){
  for(const auto& element : c){
    foo(element);
  }
}

template <typename T>
void Operate( const std::optional<T>& opt){
  if(opt.has_value()){
    foo(opt.value());
  }
}

int main(){
  std::optional<int> a = ...;
  std::vector<float> b = ...;
  ...
  Operate(a); // only executes `foo(opt.value())` if `opt` has_value().
  Operate(b); // executes `foo(element)` for each element in `c`.
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7avKsTraa)

Comment: You could write a wrapper that makes optional iterable, but probably not a good idea.  Hmm, could do every nullable dereferencible...

Comment: I was hoping & looking for a way to remove the duplicate code that this requires.